# Accessing fingerprint template from fingerprint sensor(R305)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, fingerprint, time-and-attendance

Hello i have a project to implement fingerprint attendance system for my college. I have a problem that i want to access fingerprint template from sensor R305 and store it in a database. And when user place his finger print on reader than data must be checked from data and then decision must be take.
Here scenario is that college has multiple labs and each lab have a finger print sensor. So Let say student register his fingerprint from Lab-A then if he has a lecture in Lab-B then his fingerprint must also work their.
I am using Raspberry pi zero w and R305 fingerprint sensor for this project.
Can anyone guide me?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you looked at the datasheet for the R305, or found any open source software projects that use it?

Comment: Hello, Yes i have and it has some hex code. But i dont know how to pass this code can you help me??

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. The data sheet or application notes should tell you how to do it, if its possible. Or examine other source code of projects using the R305.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done, at least in theory. I have not implemented it, but it should be possible to do. You would have to pass the hex code exactly as it is in the data sheet and it should respond to you. Make sure you are using a TTL as R305 works on 5v and Pi on 3.3, so the communication will not work properly till you use a TTL to connect the Pi and the R305 module.
You can use [this link](https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint) to try out primary operations like enrolling and searching for enrolled users. It is a great library and works with R305. Check it out and try to implement any other feature that is not available in the library.
For your scenario, you would need to use some sort of database to store and sync users that are enrolled already. [This link](http://fingerprint-module-r305-python-and-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter03.html) can help you with that. 
Hope this helps you getting a direction.